# How to grep specific extensions into list python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have a directory containing multiple file extensions, and I'd like to grep into a list the paths to all the files with 2 different extensions. So far I've tried:

```
my_files = list(Path(my_dir).glob('**/*.txt' and '**/*.txt.gz'))
```

But with the above script, I get only the paths of the `.txt.gz` files:

```
[PosixPath('/home/myproject/cd_4/M_1and2.txt.gz')]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `'foo' and 'bar'` evaluates to just `'bar'`, you either need to write a single glob pattern that matches both cases or run it once for each case and join the results.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `'ptrn1' and ptrn2'` always evaluates to `'ptrn2'`

So you definitely can't do this with a single `glob` call. Invoke `glob` separately for each pattern and merge the results

```
my_files  = list(Path('test').glob('**/*.txt'))
my_files += list(Path('test').glob('**/*.txt.gz'))
```

Or as a one-liner

```
my_files = [p for ptrn in ['**/*.txt', '**/*.txt.gz'] for p in Path('test').glob(ptrn)]
```